# as3 massive project how to decrease memory usage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

i have a big project contains upto 120 video and lots of loaded swf
the export exe file when testing it takes a massive memory usage up to 1.5 gb of ram and always crash when testing on another device
i need a way to make things lighter
all the video f4v ext
the project have a 90 frame .. every frame has the video and mc and loaded swf
i tried to convert all the graphix to mc but it did not make any change to the problem

this is example of the frame size

```
Frame #    Frame Bytes    Total Bytes    Scene
-------    -----------    -----------    -----
      1         301350         301350    Scene 1 (AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame)
      2         401105         702455    
      3         192375         894830    
      4          79164         973994    
      5         105334        1079328    
      6         262487        1341815    
      7         194283        1536098    
      8         280371        1816469    
      9         184929        2001398    
     10         146090        2147488    
     11        1879310        4026798    
     12          82537        4109335    
     13          46675        4156010    
     14          20629        4176639    
     15            522        4177161    
     16           1660        4178821    
     17         566833        4745654
```

Comment: I strongly advise to turn all the embedded videos into the loadable (and unloadable) content. I am not sure there were any options to compress the videos, and even if there are, no telling if the result is satisfactory.

Comment: what u mean loadable ? u mean like loading swf ?

Comment: I mean putting them to separate **SWF** files and load them runtime upon request.

Comment: i tryed that but the videos don't play